# node-postgres doesn't show db tables

Tags: database, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I have psql db with tables: album, genre, artist, song.

This query is supposed to return all tables that exist in my db:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'public' 
  AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

When querying it in pgAdmin, or in Terminal, I have expected result:
[image]

But, when trying to query it using node-postgres and express I have empty array in return.

This is my db configuration:

```js
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;


const env = process.env;
const db = new Pool({
    user: env.DB_USER,
    host: env.DB_HOST,
    database: env.DB_NAME,
    password: env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: env.DB_PORT,
})

module.exports = db;
```

This is testing route I use for querying:

```js
// Route to get all table names
app.get('/list-tables', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const queryText = `
        SELECT table_name 
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_schema = 'public' 
        AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
      `;
      const result = await db.query(queryText);
      const tables = result.rows.map(row => row.table_name);
      res.json(tables);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error fetching table names');
    }
});
```

I tested it in Postman and it gives me empty list.
Connection itself is fine, queries like

```
SELECT NOW()
```

work.
Encountered this problem while trying to make query to one of the tables. DB name, port, host, user are double checked. User is owner of the table.

How can I fix it?